# Capturar valor de uma função assíncrona no NodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, async

Olá, estou com um problema que ainda não encontrei solução.

Tenho um array de valores, no qual faço uma varredura e para cada valor executo função que faz uma requisição ao `dynamodb` e retorna um JSON. Esta requisição é assíncrona. Com o valor de cada consulta, desejo preencher um array, que será retornado via *callback* para minha `View`.

O problema é que, quando dou um `push` no Array, o mesmo me retorna vazio ao sair do escopo da minha função assíncrona.

```
exports.appCategory = function(ids, callback1){

    var result = { apps: []};

    async.forEachSeries(ids, function(item, cb){
            async.series([
                    function(callback){
                            //funcao assincrona
                            verify(item.id, function(res){
                                    result.apps.push(res);
                            });
                            callback();
                    },
            ]);
            cb();
    });

    console.log(result);
}
```

Minha função de consulta ao banco de dados:

```
function verify(id, callback){

    scrapeDB.getItem(id, function(response){
            var category;
            url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+id+"&hl=pt";

            if(response === null){
                    request(url, function(error, response, html){

                            if(error){
                                    console.log(error);
                                    return false;
                            }else{

                                    var $ = cheerio.load(html);

                                    if(response.statusCode == "404"){
                                            category = "Outros";
                                    }else{
                                            $('.category').filter(function(){
                                                    var data = $(this);
                                                    dataCategory = data.children().first().text();
                                                    category  = dataCategory;
                                            });
                                   }//else

                                   //save data
                                   scrapeDB.putItem(id, category, function(resp){
                                            callback(resp);
                                            //return resp;
                                   });

                            }//else       
                    });//request
            }else{
                    callback(response);
                    //return response;
            }

    });//scrapedb

}//function verify()
```

Meu resultado atual é:

```
{ apps: [] }
```

O resultado esperado é algo similar a (um Array de JSON):

```
{ apps: [{id: "value1", category: "category1"}, {id: "value1", category: "category1"}] }
```

Comment: De onde usas esse `async.forEachSeries`? no repositório do [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) não encontro esse método...

Comment: Oi @Sergio, achei neste link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15942832/nodejs-async-foreachseries-execution-order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem vários problemas no seu código mas o problema básico é que você está assumindo que a linha depois da chamada da função assíncrona só roda depois que a o servidor respondeu. Na verdade ocorre o oposto.

Por exemplo, se você rodar

```
 requestDataFromServer(function(){
     console.log("servidor respondeu");
     array.push(...)
 });
 console.log("agora tudo acabou")
```

O resultado que você provavelmente irá obter será o contrário do que você espera:

```
agora tudo acabou
servidor respondeu
```

Para resolver isso, o que você deve fazer é sempre passar um callback para as funções assíncronas e colocar todo o resto do seu fluxo de execução que depende do resultado da chamada assíncrona dentro desse callback.

```
exports.appCategory = function(ids, callback1){

    var result = { apps: []};

    async.forEachSeries(ids, function(item, cb){
        async.series([
            function(callback){
                //funcao assincrona
                verify(item.id, function(res){
                    result.apps.push(res);
                    callback();
                });
            },
        ], function(){
            cb()
        });
    }, function(){
        console.log(result);
        callback1();
    });
}
```

Além disso, tem algumas modificações que acho que deixam o código mais bonito nesse caso:

- usar assinc.series com uma lista de tamanho 1 é redundante
- `function(){ cb() }` pode ser escrito como `cb`
- Acho que o nome de verdade da função é [eachSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachSeries)

ou seja:

```
exports.appCategory = function(ids, callback1){
    var result = { apps: []};
    async.eachSeries(ids, function(item, cb){
        verify(item.id, function(res){
            result.apps.push(res);
            cb()
        });
    }, function(){
        console.log(result);
        callback1();
    });
}
```

---

ps: recomendo que você dê uma olhada na função [each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) (sem o "series") para deixar o código mais rápido e não ter que ficar dando "push".

Comment: Olá @hugomg, entendi sua resposta. Assim que puder, irei realizar as alterações e posto aqui o resultado. Grato.

Comment: @user3319937 se a resposta do Hugo resolveu o seu problema pode marcar a resposta como aceite.

Comment: Olá @hugomg, funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado pela resposta.